# Python categories not updating?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am currently making a blog but I recently added a dropdown menu for my website. From that point onwards when I add a new category it does not update. Instead it says this page does not exist when it should have.

`add_category.html` file

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block title %}Create a New Blog Category!{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    
    
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>Add Category</h1>
        <br/><br/>
    
        <div class="form-group">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button class="btn btn-secondary">Add Category</button>
    
        </div>
    
    {% else %}
    
    You are not allowed here! (and you know it...)
    
    {% endif %}
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

`categories.html` file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if category_posts %}

    <h1>{{ cats }}</h1>

    <ul>
    {% for post in category_posts %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a> - {{post.author.first_name}} {{post.author.last_name}} -  
            {{ post.post_date }} <small>

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                - <a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">(Edit)</a>

                <a href="{% url 'delete_post' post.pk %}">(Delete)</a>

            {% endif %}


        </small><br/>
        {{post.body|slice:":200"| safe }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% else %}
    <h2>Sorry this page does not exist...</h2>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py` file

```
  from django.urls import path
    #from . import views
    from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView, AddCategoryView, CategoryView
    
    urlpatterns = [
        #path('', views.home, name="home"),
        path('',HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
        path('article/<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
        path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name ='add_post'),
        path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name ='add_category'),
        path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name = 'update_post'),
        path('article/edit/<int:pk>/remove', DeletePostView.as_view(), name = 'delete_post'),
        path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
    ]
```

`base.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>
      {% block title %}
          Kaushik's blog!
      {% endblock %}
    </title>

  </head>
  <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">My Awesome Blog!</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

        <!-- Category Menu Code --->
          {% if cat_menu %}
         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Categories
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

            {% for item in cat_menu %}
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a>
            {% endfor %}

          </ul>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_post' %}">Add Post</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_category' %}"> Add Category</a>
        </li>
```

'views.py' file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, Category
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy



class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']
    

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

def CategoryListView(request):
    cat_menu_list = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category_list.html',{'cat_menu_list':cat_menu_list})



def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats.replace('-', ' '))
    return render(request, 'categories.html',{'cats':cats.title().replace('-', ' '), 'category_posts':category_posts})



class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    #fields = ('title', 'body')
    #fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(AddPostView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context


class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    #form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_category.html'
    #fields = ('title', 'body')
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(AddCategoryView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = EditForm 
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    #fields = ['title', 'title_tag', 'body']    

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(UpdatePostView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context


class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post 
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(DeletePostView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context
```

I hope someone can help me with this? I have also add some pictures for reference. If there is another file missing please type it in as a comment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGhgB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5RJA.png

Comment: Hello @KaushikJayendirakumar you have to provide `views.py`

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari I have added views.py. I hope you will be able to answer m question.

Comment: Hello @KaushikJayendirakumar try to print your `category_post` check if you get data or not and try to remove spaces when you are trying to filter for eg. `Post.objects.filter(category=cats.replace('-', ''))`   like this  `'  '` to  `''`

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari If you see I have added the category as "Websites" and when I click the category the URL changes to "websites". If I type "Websites" it works. I just want it to paste whatever it is written n the data base. That is why the other category with full lower case worked and not this.

Comment: Hello @KaushikJayendirakumar please share your category list html code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the category view is incorrect in your `urls.py`, just need to call `.as_view()` like you have with the others.

```py
path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='category'),
```

Comment: sadly that is not the problem. The problem is that the URL lowercases all the letter when clicked as you can see in those two pictures URL. I just don't know where and how to apply it.